# select query to fetch json column internal objects

Tags: postgresql

I have a json  like `{"disks":{"value":[{"Type":"NA"},{"Type":"NA"}]}}`.

How can I write a query to fetch value in Type

Answer (score 1):

You can use jsonb_array_elements() for that:

```
with sample_data (json_col) as (
  values ('{"disks":{"value":[{"Type":"NA"},{"Type":"NA"}]}}'::jsonb)
)
select x.t ->> 'Type' as type
from sample_data, jsonb_array_elements(json_col -> 'disks' -> 'value') as x(t);
```

returns

```
type
----
NA  
NA
```